# Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected for worldcloud in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, wordcloud2

I'm creating a simple Shiny UI that allow users to either input text or upload file to create a word cloud, the sidebar shows normal, but main panel continues to show

> Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected'.

Avoid initial warning with default value set in textAreaInput

Key code as below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Word Cloud"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Add radio buttons input
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "source",
        label = "Word source",
        choices = c(
          "Use your own words" = "own",
          "Upload a file" = "file"
        )
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.source == 'own'",
        textAreaInput("text", "Enter text",value="Paste here",rows = 7)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.source == 'file'",
        fileInput("file", "Select a txt file (encoding='UTF-8')")
      ),
      colourInput("col", "Background color", value = "white"),
      # Add a "draw" button to the app
      actionButton(inputId = "draw", label = "Draw!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      wordcloud2Output("cloud")
    )
  )
)

library(tidyverse)
library(jiebaR)
mixseg = worker()
server <- function(input, output) {
  data_source <- reactive({
    if (input$source == "own") {
      (data <- as.data.frame(table(mixseg <= input$text)))
    } else if (input$source == "file") {
      f<-read_file(input$file$datapath)
      if(is.null(f)){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        data <- as.data.frame(table(mixseg <=f))
      }
    } 
    return(data)
  })

  output$cloud <- renderWordcloud2({
    input$draw
    isolate(
      wordcloud2(data_source(), backgroundColor =input$col))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. `wordcloud2` requires a `data.frame` including word and frequency count in two columns. Currently you are providing `data_source()` as input which is a reactive structure that returns a single `character` string.
2. You need to properly parse the `textInput` server-side, which means that you need to create a `wordcloud2`-suitable `data.frame` from the input provided through `textAreaInput`; in fact, using `textAreaInput` is probably not the best element to use here, as your input text is highly structured and `textAreaInput` is best used for unstructured text values, see `?textAreaInput`. But let's continue with your `textAreaInput` for pedagogical purposes.
3. You should also include a check that ensures that the wordcloud only gets drawn if there is actually any data to use. We can do this using `validate`, see code below. Not including this check will result in a `Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected`.
4. Less of an issue but not helping your post in terms of clarity: You are not using `input_file` at all; ditto for `colourInput`.

Following is a minimal reproducible example (where I've removed the unnecessary parts)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(wordcloud2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Word Cloud"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        # Add radio buttons input
            radioButtons(
                inputId = "source",
                label = "Word source",
                choices = c(
                    "Use your own words" = "own",
                    "Upload a file" = "file")
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.source == 'own'",
                textAreaInput("text", "Enter comma-separated text", rows = 7)
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.source == 'file'",
                fileInput("file", "Select a file")
            )
        ),
        mainPanel(
            wordcloud2Output("cloud")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data_source <- reactive({
        if (input$text != "")
            as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(input$text, "[, ]"))))
        else
            NULL
    })

    output$cloud <- renderWordcloud2({
        validate(need(data_source(), "Awaiting data"))
        wordcloud2(data_source(), backgroundColor = "white")
    })
}
```

This produces e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks much! I've enhanced the code accordingly, and now it works for both text and file. However, the error '[.data.frame: undefined columns selected' still shows at beginning when no input in sidebar...

Comment: @crelyz Your enhanced code doesn't check for empty data hence the error. Take a look at my example above, specifically the `validate` part.